# Having difficulty printing all the values of a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to print out the values of an array in JavaScript and I keep receiving 'undefined' output in the Chrome developer console where I'm running the following code:

```
function printArray(){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr = arr[i];
  }
}
printArray(['hello','world',1,2,3]);
```

Will someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong here that is preventing me from seeing the following returned in the console?

```
['hello','world',1,2,3]
```

Additionally I've tried wrapping my call to the `printArray` function inside of a `console.log();` statement.

```
console.log(printArray(['hello','world',1,2,3]));
```

Comment: you have to pass the array into the function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/no789fh2/

Comment: Thank you Gholamali.  I see this now and it seems like quite the oversight now with six months of hindsight and practice behind me.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to pass the array as argument to the function. Second, inside the function you can use the `console.log` to print each item of the array.

```js
function printArray(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
printArray(['hello','world',1,2,3]);
```

You can also use `console.log(['hello','world',1,2,3])` without the need of the `printArray` function

Comment: might be worth noting that you can console.log the entire array as it is

Comment: Thank you.  It was part of an exercise in calling it within a function (using a for loop).  Iterating over the array and printing out the values to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

This will print all the values in the array:

```
function printArray(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}

printArray(['hello','world',1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you wouldn't just console log the whole array?

```
console.log(['hello','world',1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Please see my response above to xavvvier.  Primary purpose here was to iterate through the array values using a for loop.